# How to add baker framework to my project?

Tags: cocoapods

I'm developing an ebook app.

I think the [baker framework](http://bakerframework.com/) is a good idea. According to the official tutorial, I need to download a sample xcode project, change some configuration, and add my books folder to it.

But I have my own project using [cocoa pod](http://cocoapods.org/).I would like to integrate baker framework into my project, how to do that?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. Have you followed precisely what the documentation says?

Comment: @Lukas1 I have update my problem, is that all right?

Answer (score 1):

As per [github link](https://github.com/germanocaldeira/baker)

1) Download the Baker Framework Xcode project from http://bakerframework.com (or GitHub).

2) Download Xcode from the Mac App Store or from the Apple Developer website.

3) Open Baker in Xcode.

4) Add all the files of your publication from your "book/" folder to the "book/" folder inside Baker.

5) Rename the project to the name of your publication: click on the "Baker" name in the leftmost column of the project navigator.

6) Replace the icon files (ios-icon-*.png, check the Apple Guidelines for reference).
7) Change the bundle identifier in the plist file to the one you are going to use for your app.

8) Select the Baker Scheme (Simulator or Device) from the toolbar dropdown.
Run and check that everything works correctly both on simulator and device.

Exaplained neatly in the above github link.You don't expect any better steps/explanation than it is given in the github link.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to add baker framework to my project via **cocoapods**.